# How does lightning flip a car?

Tags: electromagnetism, lightning

http://www.standard.co.uk/news/london/car-flips-into-air-after-being-struck-by-lightning-in-freak-electrical-storm-accident-10366208.html and a few others (http://news.google.com/news/i/story?ncl=dkFcFfRVsPya_4MlZGvJnKZl6jfBM) claim that a lightning bolt flipped a car. By what mechanism can that happen? Is electromotive force that strong? Its tyres look like they haven't burst.

Comment: Maybe better for "skeptics"?  As the story suggests the car was in motion at the time, then I think it more likely that the bolt startled the driver.  Lightning can vaporize materials (enough to explode struck trees), but I think it unlikely that it would simply toss a car.

Comment: @BowlOfRed Yes I think that driver fright is the likeliest explanation too, unless the lightning struck something that would explode on vaporization near the car. Since there are only witness accounts as data and little chance to do a controlled experiment, one really can't go much further on this.

Comment: Agreed-- it doesn't.  Just because some low-class rags post a headline and a google agglomerator links to the story doesn't make it true.

Comment: Yup, I thought it sounded dubious but just checked if there was a mechanism I'm unaware of.